# Extract phone number from complicated string

Tags: regex

Assume we got address book with some unformatted data, like:

> +1 (4542) 114214 111@111.org      d@ghhg.com,,,,
>
> +1 (2342) 114234 ert@nhy.sdfr.domain.org; 1@kjk.eiu.1
>
> +7 (101) 111-222-11  abc@ert.com, def@sdf.org
>
> +1 (102) 123532-2 some@mail.ru
>
> +44 (301) 123 23 45 7zip@site.edu; ret@ghjj.org

I made attempts to write regex for this:

> /+\d+\s(\d+)\s\d+[\d+\s | \d+ -]+/g

But i have no idea how to exclude numbers before alphabetical characters. Probably this is not even a partial solution.

Edit #1: I'm overwhelmed by all working solutions provided, many thanks to everyone. If possible, i would be grateful if you added at least some reference/explanation how to write such complicated regex.

Comment: which flavor is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing where you are using this regex I'd recommend using a negative lookahead.

```
^[+\d() -]+(?![\w@])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rQ6fK4/1

If you want to capture the phone number use:

```
^([+\d() -]+)(?![\w@])
```

It will be in `$1` or `\1`, (depending on where you are using this).

Comment: This looks great. Can you please give some advice on what should i read/try to learn how to write expression like this? Just finished regexone tutorial.

Comment: I'd recommend trying your regex's on regex101. It gives you a breakdown on the right of what is occurring. I'd look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and http://www.rexegg.com/, there is a lot of information there though.

Answer (score 0):

That may be one of few cases, where you need a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

My [attempt](https://regex101.com/r/oA3yS0/2):

```
\s*(\+?(\d+)\s*\(\d+\)\s+([- \d+]++(?!\@)|\d+))
```

The part `[- \d+]++(?!\@)` will stop the matching if a "@" is following. Therefore it excludes the e-mail addresses.

The phone numbers are now stored in group 1.

**Edit:**
Yes, the last input line doesn't match correctley. Maybe it's easier to extract the e-mail addresses with the following regex, so the phone numbers are left (and some commas, but they should be a problem to extract as well):

```
\s[^\@ ]+\@[-\w.]+\.\w+
```

Comment: Look out for that `7zip@site.edu`, looks like your capturing the start of that email address.

Comment: The last case in example, your regex will extract 7 from "7zip@site.edu" email. Still, your solutions looks closer to what I'm looking for, thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pP8lM8/3):

```
(?<phone>\+\d{1,2}\s\(\d{3,4}\)\s(?:[\d- ]+\d)(?=\s)) 
\s+(?<email>.*?@.*?)(?=[\s;,]|$).*?
\s+(?<email2>[\w]*?@.*?)?(?=[\s;,]|$)
```

Which produce:

```
MATCH 1
phone   [4-20]  `+1 (4542) 114214`
email   [21-32] `111@111.org`
email2  [33-43] `d@ghhg.com`
MATCH 2
phone   [52-68] `+1 (2342) 114234`
email   [69-92] `ert@nhy.sdfr.domain.org`
email2  [94-105]    `1@kjk.eiu.1`
MATCH 3
phone   [110-129]   `+7 (101) 111-222-11`
email   [130-141]   `abc@ert.com`
email2  [143-154]   `def@sdf.org`
MATCH 4
phone   [159-176]   `+1 (102) 123532-2`
email   [177-189]   `some@mail.ru`
MATCH 5
phone   [194-213]   `+44 (301) 123 23 45`
email   [214-227]   `7zip@site.edu`
email2  [229-241]   `ret@ghjj.org`
```

---

Explanation:

```
(?<phone>\+\d{1,2}\s\(\d{3,4}\)\s(?:[\d- ]+\d)(?=\s)) Named capturing group phone

    \+ matches the character + literally
    \d{1,2} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {1,2} Between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    \( matches the character ( literally
    \d{3,4} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {3,4} Between 3 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \) matches the character ) literally
    \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    (?:[\d- ]+\d) Non-capturing group
        [\d- ]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \d match a digit [0-9]
            - a single character in the list - literally
        \d match a digit [0-9]
    (?=\s) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

(?<email>.*?@.*?) Named capturing group email

    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
    @ matches the character @ literally
    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

(?=[\s;,]|$) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

    1st Alternative: [\s;,]
        [\s;,] match a single character present in the list below
            \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
            ;, a single character in the list ;, literally
    2nd Alternative: $
        $ assert position at end of a line

.*? matches any character (except newline)

    Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

\s+ match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

(?<email2>[\w]*?@.*?)? Named capturing group email2

    Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
    [\w]*? match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
        \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    @ matches the character @ literally
    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

(?=[\s;,]|$) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched

    1st Alternative: [\s;,]
        [\s;,] match a single character present in the list below
            \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
            ;, a single character in the list ;, literally
    2nd Alternative: $
        $ assert position at end of a line

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
x modifier: extended. Spaces and text after a # in the pattern are ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution (on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iR6jH4/1)):

`\+\d+\s+\(\d+\)\s+[- \d]+(?= )`

It ensures the last group of spaces, digits, and/or dashes (`[- \d]+`) is followed by a space (`(?= )`).

It cleanly captures all of your examples, without trailing spaces, and without including any part of the email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even try parsing the phone number.

You have a phone number, separated with a space character from one or more email addresses, which are separated by commas or semicolons. An email address always contains a @.

Find the first @. If there is none then the phone number is the trimmed string. If there is an @ then find the last space before the @. The phone number is the everything up to that space, trimmed. If there is no space before the @ then you have no phone number.

With phone numbers removed, you can find the emails by splitting the string around "," or ";", trimming the strings, and throwing away what doesn't contain an @.

Then find a decent number to handle phone numbers, if you need to do that beyond recording what the phone number is.